# SWIFTUI : get date only

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I'm trying to do something, and search, but I found nothing. I have a function DatePicker in a file. I call this function and send to it a binding var date. I want to keep only date and remove time from it. I have this function :

```
     var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
     let formatter = DateFormatter()
     formatter.dateStyle = .medium
     formatter.timeStyle = .none
     return formatter
 }
```

But I use it like this : Text("(date, formatter: dateFormatter)")

How I can return the binding value with this formatter ?

thank you

edit my file :

```
struct WIDatePicker: View {

@Binding var date: Date

@State private var sheetDate = false

 var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
     let formatter = DateFormatter()
     formatter.dateStyle = .medium
     formatter.timeStyle = .none
     return formatter
 }



var body: some View {

    Button(action: {self.sheetDate.toggle()}) {

        VStack {

                HStack {

                    Text("\(date, formatter: dateFormatter)")
                    Print("Variables : \(dateFormatter.string(from: date))")

                    Spacer()


            if (sheetDate == true) {

                Divider()
                DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date)
                    .labelsHidden()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking how to use the formatter. Use it like this:

```
Text("date \(date, formatter: dateFormatter)")
```

Comment: No, this is ok. My problem is to apply this function to a binding var. I've edit my first post with the swift file. I want to have my binding var Date with no time.

Comment: Date represents time, to have a date with no time does not make sense to me. The formating just changes the "looks" of the date, not its value. The hours, minutes, seconds, ... are still there.

Even if you set the hours and minutes and seconds components to zero, that would still represent midnight.

Maybe you could store your date in another var as a string and use that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could do something like this, to get the string date without hours and minutes.

```
struct WIDatePicker: View {

@State var date: Date
@State private var sheetDate = false
@State var myDateString = ""

var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    return formatter
}

var body: some View {
    let bindingDate = Binding<Date>(
        get: { self.date },
        set: {
            self.myDateString =  self.dateFormatter.string(from: $0)
            self.date = $0
    })

    return Button(action: {
        self.sheetDate.toggle()
    }) {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("\(self.myDateString)")
                Spacer()
                if (sheetDate == true) {
                    Divider()
                    DatePicker("", selection: bindingDate, displayedComponents: .date).labelsHidden()
                }
            }
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
}

func loadData() {
    myDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

}

Comment: Thaaaaanks ! This is exactly what I want ! thank you very much !

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If this answer your question, please mark it as such, thanks.